# Select rows with nearest date

Tags: sql, date, exists

I have a SQL  statement.

```
SELECT ID, LOCATION, CODE,MAX(DATE) FROM TABLE1 WHERE 
DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-11-2012') AND 
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TEMP_CODE WHERE TABLE1.CODE =#TEMP_CODE.CODE) 
AND ID IN (14,279)
GROUP BY ID, LOCATION, CODE,(DATE)
```

I need rows with the nearest date to the 11-11-2012, but the table returns all the values.  What am I doing wrong. Thanks

```
ID     LOCATION                 CODE            DATE
-------------------------------------------------------------------
14  CAR STREET,UDUPI            234   2012-08-08 00:00:00.000
14  CAR STREET,UDUPI            234   2012-08-10 00:00:00.000
14  CAR STREET,UDUPI            234   2012-08-14 00:00:00.000
279 MADHUGIRI                   234   2012-08-08 00:00:00.000
279 MADHUGIRI                   234   2012-08-11 00:00:00.000
```

I need to select the row with the max date. The required result is

```
ID     LOCATION                 CODE            DATE
-------------------------------------------------------------------
14  CAR STREET,UDUPI            234   2012-08-10 00:00:00.000
279 MADHUGIRI                   234   2012-08-11 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Some thing is wrong. You have written `AND ID IN ('KBL01005','KBL05020')` and you are getting id with 14 and 279

Comment: You should accept the appropriate answer which help you. So that answer also helps other peoples.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `(DATE)` from the `GROUP BY` Clause.

Change

```
SELECT ID, LOCATION, CODE,MAX(DATE) FROM TABLE1 WHERE  
DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-11-2012') AND  
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TEMP_CODE WHERETABLE1.CODE =#TEMP_CODE.CODE)  
AND ID IN ('KBL01005','KBL05020') 
GROUP BY ID, LOCATION, CODE,(DATE)
```

to

```
SELECT ID, LOCATION, CODE,MAX(DATE) FROM TABLE1 WHERE  
DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-11-2012') AND  
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TEMP_CODE WHERETABLE1.CODE =#TEMP_CODE.CODE)  
AND ID IN ('KBL01005','KBL05020') 
GROUP BY ID, LOCATION, CODE
```

Comment: Thanks but the result is the same.. it returns all the five rows. I actually require only rows with dates 2012-08-14 and 2012-08-11

Comment: That is what I would have expected to see, unless there is something else the you left out of your query.

Comment: @Prince: try with `GROUP BY ID, CODE`. Maybe the locations are not identical (invisible white space)

Comment: Thanks friends...I was having another field in the select statement that was not identical. Now everything working fine

Answer (score 1):

Try using unambigious date format

```
SELECT ID, LOCATION, CODE,MAX(DATE) FROM TABLE1 
WHERE DATE <= '20121111' AND   
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TEMP_CODE WHERETABLE1.CODE =#TEMP_CODE.CODE)   
AND ID IN ('KBL01005','KBL05020')  
GROUP BY ID, LOCATION, CODE
```

Also see why you need to use unambigious date formats http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10898/understanding-datetime-column-part-ii.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `Group by (Date)`. Try this:

```
SELECT ID, LOCATION, CODE,MAX(DATE) FROM TABLE1 
WHERE DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-11-2012') AND 
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TEMP_CODE WHERE TABLE1.CODE =#TEMP_CODE.CODE) 
AND ID IN (14,279)
GROUP BY ID, LOCATION, CODE
```